Parallel feature files execution in Cucumber with TestNG runner?
How to run multiple feature files parallely in cucumber with TestNG runner?
 <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <parallel>tests</parallel>
                    <useUnlimitedThreads>true</useUnlimitedThreads>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                    <properties>
                        <property>
                            <name>dataproviderthreadcount</name>
                            <value>20</value>
                        </property>
                    </properties>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>


@CucumberOptions(glue = { "stepDefinitions" }, features = { "src/test/resources/features" })

public class TestRunner {
    private TestNGCucumberRunner testNGCucumberRunner;

    @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void setUpClass() {
        testNGCucumberRunner = new TestNGCucumberRunner(this.getClass());
    }

    @Test(groups = "cucumber scenarios", description = "Runs Cucumber Scenarios", dataProvider = "scenarios")
    public void scenario(PickleWrapper pickleEvent, FeatureWrapper cucumberFeature) throws Throwable {
        testNGCucumberRunner.runScenario(pickleEvent.getPickle());
    }

    @DataProvider(parallel = true)
    public Object[][] scenarios() {
        return testNGCucumberRunner.provideScenarios();
    }

    @AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void tearDownClass() {
        testNGCucumberRunner.finish();
    }

}

